# Google BigQuery, How to load data from google cloud storage to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am switching to Big Query due to high performance.
But have no idea about how to upload data from Google Cloud Storage to Big Query Database.
Some more questions...
Can i directly access my database from google cloud storage while using Big Query.
Will i have to convert it first to some format.
How i will keep updating Big Query database to my Google Cloud Storage Database.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a supported format (delimited such as csv/tsv or json), you can easily load your data from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery using either UI, CLI or API. For example, using the CLI:

```
bq load mydataset.mytable gs://my_bucket/file.csv name:string,gender:string,count:integer
```

This will load file.csv from your Google Cloud Storage bucket 'my_bucket' into table 'mytable' under 'mydataset' dataset. The table will have three columns, - name and gender of type string and count of type integer. It might be useful for you to review the BigQuery Quick Start guide [1]

If you need to add more data, just run the `bq load` command again and by default, it will append the new rows from the CSV to the BigQuery's table. If you need to overwrite the data, add the `--replace` flag, so it will erase existing contents before loading new data

More, you can even run queries on your files in Google Cloud Storage without loading them first into BigQuery using External Tables [2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool-quickstart

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources

Comment: You give solution to just upload first time, what if i want to upload in append mode, or overwrite mode

Comment: @deepanshudagar - I added a section in my answer to explain the append/overwrite options.

Comment: Thanks for including the --replace flag, that's what I was looking for, and I didn't see it in any of their online doc. It's definitely there though if you look at `bq help load`

Answer (score 0):

Using Python U can update as :

```
import numpy as np
import uuid
from gcloud import bigquery


def load_data_from_gcs(dataset_name, table_name, source):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
    table = dataset.table(table_name)
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    if table.exists():
        table.delete()
    table.schema = (
        bigquery.SchemaField('ID', 'STRING'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('days', 'STRING'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('last_activ_date', 'STRING'),


    )

    table.create()
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(
        job_name, table, source)

    job.begin()

    wait_for_job(job)

    print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(
        job.output_rows, dataset_name, table_name))

def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_data_from_gcs('my_model','my_output', 'gs://path-uat/data_project/my_output.csv')
```